# HighCharts Stacked column

Tags: highcharts

I'm using HighCharts, I have this array,

[image]

I would like to create a chart like this:

[image]

As I know, the format of series is like this:

```
series:[{
        name: 'Production',
        data: [0.074, 0.040,0.034,0.036,0.068]
    }, {
        name: 'Reprise',
        data: [0.024,0.022,0.029, 0.055, 0.052]
    }]
```

with categories array:

```
['Mario', 'Andre', 'Jean Jacques', 'Fidy', 'Judith']
```

How could I do if I want to paste each value of column Volumes to each Production Stacked Bar value like the chart above ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Yes of course, see here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/AimeJean/zgzLwo5x/1/)

Comment: You  can add new object to your chart options and use it inside dataLabels.formatter: https://jsfiddle.net/zgzLwo5x/2/ if my example will work for you, I will post it as an answer

Comment: Thanks you, that is what I was looking for! It work  for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/

```
series: [{
```

> ```
>         name: 'Volume',
>         data: [1, 0.16, 0.46, 0.37, 0.24]
>     }, {
>         name: 'Reprise',
>         data: [0.024, 0.0.....]
>     }, {
>         name: 'Production',
>         data: [....]
>     }]
> ```

Later edit: to display volume as data label you can use the formatter function:

```
column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.x;//you can have a little logic here if (thix.x == 'Production) return myVariable[y];myVariable will contains values from volume or something similar
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: My problem is: I want each value of column Volumes become dataLabels like the chart above.  This is my JSFiddle :[link](https://jsfiddle.net/AimeJean/zgzLwo5x/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Define volume in your data array:

```
data: [{y:0.074,volume:1}, {y:0.040,volume:0.15}]
```

And use formatter in datalabels options to get custom value:

```
formatter: function () {
    return this.point.volume + ' km';   
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asadsarwar89/2f760we7/)